# Convert Microsoft Word equations to Latex

Tags: python, ms-word, latex, equation, python-docx

I have a docx file containing a few equations in different pages. With Python and lxml, I was successful in extracting the content. I now need to convert the equations in Word to Latex. Some of the equations are shown as:

```
- eq \\f (sinx,\\r(1 - sin 2 x))
```

Is there any Python library of any tool that I can use to convert the equation to Latex format?

Here is a snippet of the XML file which I obtained from docxfile/word/document.xml:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00677018" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5" w:rsidRDefault="00677018" w:rsidP="00677018">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="w" />
                <w:jc w:val="both" /></w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:tab/>
                <w:t>a.</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:tab/></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" /></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">eq \b\bc\[(\a\co2\hs4(7,-3,-1,2))</w:instrText>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" /></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:tab/>
                <w:t>b.</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:tab/></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" /></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">eq \f(5,8)</w:instrText>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" /></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" /></w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">eq \b\bc\[(\a\co2\hs4(7,-3,-1,2))</w:instrText>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00453EF1" w:rsidRPr="007D05E5">
                <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" /></w:r>
        </w:p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this constitutes an answer per se, but perhaps on the way to one.

I went looking for such a tool a while back and didn't find one, so I think the short answer is no.

Word supports more than one format for equations. The type you have is known as a "Word EQ Field equation". http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-eq-equation-field-HP005186148.aspx

I don't find any Python solutions for this on search, and I know for certain python-docx doesn't support it. Wish I had better news for you :(

If you're determined, there appear to be some non-Python solutions out there that do this conversion, they might be an alternative or an example to study if you decide to whip one up yourself :)

Comment: Thank you. I have just added the snippet of XML file.